# tkColorChooser color testing

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I have a question about tkColorChooser. I am working on a GUI for plotting functions and a user of the program has to pick the color of the function they want to plot. I would like to test whether the color they pick is a valid tkColorChooser color.

I was thinking about doing tests such as len(colorString) == 7 (or 4) or colorString.startswith('#'), but I would still have to do testing for the color names such as 'black' and 'green' and all other colors available... It all seems like a lot of work, so I was wondering if there is an easier way to do that?

I am interested in a test such as

```
string = 'black'
Is string a valid color ?
return True

string = 'blac'
Is string a valid color?
return False
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call the method `winfo_rgb` on the root window, giving it a string that represents a color. If the color is valid you'll get the red, green and blue components. If it is invalid you will get an exception.

See http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.winfo_rgb-method

Answer (score 0):

Are you having the user type in a color name? If so, why not instead let the user pick the color directly from the tkColorChooser? That way, whatever color the user picks is a valid color by definition.

This example comes from [Jan Bodnar (zetcode.com)](http://zetcode.com/gui/tkinter/dialogs/):

```
import Tkinter as tk
class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)   
        self.parent = parent        
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.parent.title("Color chooser")      
        self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

        self.btn = tk.Button(self, text="Choose Color", command=self.onChoose)
        self.btn.place(x=30, y=30)

        self.frame = tk.Frame(self, border=1, 
                              relief=tk.SUNKEN, width=100, height=100)
        self.frame.place(x=160, y=30)

    def onChoose(self):
        rgb, hx = tkColorChooser.askcolor()
        print(rgb)
        print(hx)
        self.frame.config(bg=hx)

root = tk.Tk()
ex = Example(root)
root.geometry("300x150+300+300")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thank you, I also thought about this, but unfortunately my program must be interactive so that the user gives an input and i have to test for the possible errors...